# rust, quick-xml, serde : How can I implement complex type which has 'xsd:choice'?

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I want to implement the following XML Schema as the data structure for Rust using quick-xml and serde.

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="CT_TwoCellAnchor">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="from" type="CT_Marker" />
      <xsd:group ref="EG_ObjectChoices" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:group name="EG_ObjectChoices">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xsd:element name="sp" type="CT_Shape" />
      <!-- ...more elements... -->
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:group>
```

Now, I implemented such as the following

```rust
use quick_xml::de::from_str;
use quick_xml::se::to_string;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[serde(rename(serialize = "xdr:twoCellAnchor", deserialize = "twoCellAnchor"))]
struct CtTwoCellAnchor {
    #[serde(rename(serialize = "xdr:from", deserialize = "from"))]
    from: CtMarker,
    #[serde(rename = "$value")]
    objects: EGObjectChoices,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
enum EGObjectChoices {
    #[serde(rename(serialize = "xdr:sp", deserialize = "sp"))]
    Sp(CtShape),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct CtShape {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct CtMarker {}

fn main() {
    let obj = CtTwoCellAnchor {
        from: CtMarker {},
        objects: EGObjectChoices::Sp(CtShape {}),
    };
    let s = to_string(&obj);
    assert!(s.is_ok());
    eprintln!("{:#?}", s.unwrap());

    const XML: &'static str = r#"
    <xdr:twoCellAnchor>
        <xdr:from />
        <xdr:sp />
    </xdr:twoCellAnchor>
    "#;

    let anchor = from_str::<CtTwoCellAnchor>(XML);
    if let Err(e) = anchor.as_ref() {
        println!("{e}");
    }
    assert!(anchor.is_ok());
    eprintln!("{:#?}", anchor.unwrap());
}
```

And the outputs are the following

```
"<xdr:twoCellAnchor><xdr:from/><xdr:sp/></xdr:twoCellAnchor>"
unknown variant `from`, expected `sp`
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: anchor.is_ok()', examples/quick-xml-serde-example.rs:47:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Serialize seems to be working, but deserialize does not seem to be working.

In this case, how should I fix my implementation ?